# Default pull request to parent branch rather than master branch in Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, pull-request

When initiating a pull request through Visual Studio for a repository hosted in visual studio team services the pull request always defaults to master branch.

[image]

This default to master is independent of which branch I originally branched off from.

It's obviously trivial to change it on the menu I have highlighted each time but I would really like to find a setting somewhere that makes this default to the PARENT branch of the child I am pulling from.

Does such a setting exist?

Comment: Just to clarify - you might have a dev branch that you then branch off of, and you'd like the pull request to automatically detect that as a default when submitting a PR through Visual Studio?

Comment: @BrianaSwift Yes, exactly that

Comment: If there is a possibility to do that with Visual Studio, I don't know of it. I also don't know of any functionality to do that within Git, even from the CLI. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There's no concept of branch hierarchy in Git, so there's no way for VSTS to be aware of where a branch originated from. Branches are just pointers to commits.