# Can Azure Devops run a script to determine the default target branch for a pull request?

Tags: azure-devops, git-branch, pull-request

QUESTION:
If I were to find a script/command that gives the branch name that I want...  Is Azure Dev Ops able to run that command/script when a New Pull Request is created to set the default target branch?

DETAILS:
I'm fairly confident that I have used a pull request system in the past that correctly chose the parent branch as the target branch for pull requests more than 90% of the time.

Now I'm using Azure Dev Ops, and it does not...  Azure dev ops has a single default target branch for all pull requests.  I'm looking for a way to make this dynamic...

I've found this related question from a while ago:
[Default pull request to parent branch rather than master branch in Visual Studio Team Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877214/default-pull-request-to-parent-branch-rather-than-master-branch-in-visual-studio)

I've also found scripts that can fairly reliably determine the parent branch, by parsing/grepping results of git commands such as:
git log --first-parent
or
git show-branch

here are some example scripts:
[Git log first parent and follow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49483901/git-log-first-parent-and-follow)

here's another example scripts:
https://gist.github.com/joechrysler/6073741

I see how to set a single static target branch here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/change-default-branch?view=azure-devops#set-a-new-default-branch
I would like it to be dynamic based on a script.

I'm not the admin of an Azure Dev Ops project, if Azure Dev Ops can run a script to set the target branch when creating a pull request I will get a script ready and propose it to to the admin.

Comment: When you open a PR, you can choose the source and target branches. What's the issue?

Comment: I think the answer is no, but even if it was yes, I don't think you want to do it "when a New Pull Request is *created*", but perhaps *before* it's created so that the pre-selected target branch on the new PR screen is the one you desire.

Comment: Side Note, as mentioned in the answer of the first question you linked to, Git doesn't have a concept of parent branch, in the sense that you can't know (with certainty) which branch a new branch started from. That being said, I can think of some logic that would work *most* of the time, against a small set of shared branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure DevOps, every time when creating a new pull request, you need to specify the target branch. If you do not specify, the default branch (such as **`master`**, **`main`**, etc..) of current repository will be set as the target branch by default.

There is no way to change the default target branch, it will be always the default branch of repository, but you can change the default branch of repository from a branch to another one.

---

There is an azure DevOps CLI command "[**`az repos pr create`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/pr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-repos-pr-create)" can run in script to create new pull request. On this command, you can specify the target branch and source branch.

You can manually run this command locally, or run it in Azure Pipelines using a command task (such as [Bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/pr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-repos-pr-create), [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines), etc..).

Below is an example script to run the **`az repos pr create`** command.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

pat="{PAT}"
org="{organization}"
proj="{project}"
repo="{Repository}"
sourceBranch="{sourceBranch}"
targetBranch="{targetBranch}"
title="{title}"

echo $pat | az devops login --org https://dev.azure.com/$org

az repos pr create -p $proj -r $repo -s $sourceBranch -t $targetBranch --title "$title"
```